# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderator, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Space Exploration breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  7          9
Users destroyed                                  11          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                  23          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            77      1,190
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               11        472
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         24        936
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        370
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 9      1,583
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               55      1,889
Tags merged                                       4          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             5          1
Tag synonyms created                              5          0
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                               39         31
Questions protected                               5         44
Questions migrated                               19          1
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                                1        252
Questions closed                                133        374
Question flags handled⁴                         158         95
Posts unlocked                                    1          5
Posts undeleted                                  18         71
Posts locked                                      4         43
Posts deleted⁵                                  392        687
Posts bumped                                      0        114
Escalations to the CM team                        4          0
Comments undeleted                               11          0
Comments flagged                                  0        766
Comments deleted⁶                             1,605      3,984
Comment flags handled                           433        333
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                   9      1,248
Answer flags handled                            844        413
All comments on a post moved to chat             45          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://space.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the moderators for all their work.

I had no idea they could *destroy* users, I will be much more careful in future.

[image]

Comment: You are too big to destroy, we can only squash ants. But yeah...