# What are SE's "vital signs"

Tags: discussion

My unsubstantiated impression is that the SE site has become less active over the last year in terms of # of new questions, posted answers, etc. Is this true? Are there stats available?

Comment: Have you looked at https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/2022-a-year-in-moderation and the link to the data for the prior year?

Comment: There's certainly been a rising tide of BS.

Comment: "My unsubstantiated impression is that the SE site has become less active over the last year in terms of # of new questions, posted answers, etc. " and yet you've accepted the first answer to be posted, which as far as I can tell *doesn't say anything* about the number of new questions or answers.

Comment: I think a small number of high-activity users significantly reduced participation over 2021-2022, and I suspect that SpaceX flights were generating a _lot_ of questions from 2015-2020 as they were frequently doing new and exciting things (like landing boosters or blowing up); they're pretty routine now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think uhoh's criticism was correct, so I desperately tried to remember what little SQL I learned a couple years back and eventually refined that into the query 
[What are Space SE's Vital Signs (Count of Questions and Answers by Year)](https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/1717962/what-are-space-ses-vital-signs-count-of-questions-and-answers-by-year?opt.textResults=true)

The raw query results:

| Year | Q (1) or A (2) | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2013 | 1 | 982 |
| 2013 | 2 | 1436 |
| 2014 | 1 | 1006 |
| 2014 | 2 | 1808 |
| 2015 | 1 | 1357 |
| 2015 | 2 | 2311 |
| 2016 | 1 | 1672 |
| 2016 | 2 | 2706 |
| 2017 | 1 | 1523 |
| 2017 | 2 | 2240 |
| 2018 | 1 | 2758 |
| 2018 | 2 | 4117 |
| 2019 | 1 | 2661 |
| 2019 | 2 | 3877 |
| 2020 | 1 | 2435 |
| 2020 | 2 | 3353 |
| 2021 | 1 | 2201 |
| 2021 | 2 | 3057 |
| 2022 | 1 | 1249 |
| 2022 | 2 | 1896 |
| 2023 | 1 | 194 |
| 2023 | 2 | 290 |

And a quick chart with 2023 omitted since it isn't complete

[image: line chart showing questions and answers from 2013 to now. both peak in 2018 then trail off as time continues]

It looks like the data supports your impression:  Space Exploration is becoming less active, and has been since 2018, though the year-to-year dropoff was pretty steep between 2021 and 2022.

[Google sheet where I put the data into Markdown and then into a chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aJdRzXZBQMky2OWSPD9RfdjMMZtyzQuutj20PfLZpig/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: my SQL knowledge is *very* rough, so someone else should probably check that I haven't accidentally made all of the numbers very wrong.  I did cross-check the eventual output against a much simpler "how many questions only each year" query and got consistent data and was satisfied, though

Comment: Great info, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The [2021](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/2021-a-year-in-moderation) and [2022 "year in moderation" posts](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/2022-a-year-in-moderation)  posts don't follow exactly the same format.  I'm not completely confident I merged them correctly, so [here's the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HqGJeW60at-e7-R9cjLeYzN1U_qXEwrMDW1D_GzTOgE/edit?usp=sharing) where I gave it a shot (or if folks want to add prior years etc).  I believe the footnotes were identical between both posts; I haven't attempted to correct them.

| Action (2021) | Moderators | Community¹ | Action (2022) | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 34 | 0 | All comments on a post moved to chat | 15 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 463 | 450 | Answer flags handled | 402 | 289 |
| Answers flagged | 0 | 915 | Answers flagged | 0 | 689 |
| Comment flags handled | 273 | 52 | Comment flags handled | 535 | 856 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 986 | 2,175 | Comments deleted⁷ | 921 | 1,790 |
| Comments flagged | 0 | 329 | Comments flagged | 0 | 1,387 |
| Comments undeleted | 5 | 0 | Comments undeleted | 2 | 0 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 2 | 0 |  |  |  |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 91 | Posts bumped | 0 | 83 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 207 | 674 | Posts deleted⁶ | 224 | 493 |
| Posts locked | 3 | 36 | Posts locked | 2 | 24 |
| Posts undeleted | 20 | 70 | Posts undeleted | 6 | 36 |
|  |  |  | Posts unlocked | 1 | 1 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 95 | 75 | Question flags handled⁵ | 77 | 171 |
| Questions closed | 32 | 289 | Questions closed | 34 | 223 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 1 | 176 | Questions flagged⁵ | 9 | 249 |
| Questions merged | 3 | 0 |  |  |  |
| Questions migrated | 15 | 2 | Questions migrated | 3 | 1 |
| Questions protected | 1 | 20 | Questions protected | 2 | 13 |
| Questions reopened | 11 | 20 | Questions reopened | 2 | 7 |
|  |  |  | Questions unprotected | 0 | 1 |
| Revisions redacted | 1 | 0 | Revisions redacted | 2 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 9 | 0 | Tag synonyms created | 1 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 9 | 1 | Tag synonyms proposed | 1 | 0 |
| Tags merged | 10 | 0 | Tags merged | 2 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 0 | 1,241 | Tasks reviewed⁴: "Close votes" queue | 9 | 947 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue | 0 | 135 | Tasks reviewed⁴: "First answers" queue | 0 | 347 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 0 | 723 |  |  |  |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue | 0 | 175 | Tasks reviewed⁴: "First questions" queue | 2 | 436 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 0 | 266 | Tasks reviewed⁴: "Late answers" queue | 1 | 221 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 0 | 681 | Tasks reviewed⁴: "Low quality posts" queue | 2 | 589 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 1 | 256 | Tasks reviewed⁴: "Reopen votes" queue | 6 | 189 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 5 | 796 | Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue | 21 | 1,082 |
| Users contacted | 15 | 0 | Users contacted | 17 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 6 | 0 | Users deleted | 15 | 0 |
| Users destroyed³ | 14 | 0 | Users destroyed³ | 6 | 0 |
| Users suspended² | 11 | 16 | Users suspended² | 13 | 26 |

Comment: The review tasks are the closest of any of those metrics to actual site activity.

Comment: Is there really no way to find out if this "...site has become less active over the last year in terms of # of new questions, posted answers..."? The recent Q/day for example is 2.8 according to the summary at https://stackexchange.com/sites (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz21e.png) I wonder if there's a plot somewhere that shows the trend over the last few years?

Comment: @uhoh presumably https://data.stackexchange.com/space/queries can be made to do it (I didn't look through all the saved queries to see if one already existed, but I looked through some).  I agree this was not a great answer

Answer (score 4):

While mods cannot share specifics, the analytics tooling we have shows that total number of visits has been pretty constant over the last year (since May 2022 - prior to that numbers were higher but the reporting changed with Google analytics) with a wee dip at the turn of the year that bounced back.

New visitors is a bit more variable, but again generally trending level.

All in all, pretty good. Especially as some sites have been seeing significant downturn in numbers. See [questions like this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387278/154443) regarding impact of ChatGPT.

Answer (score 2):

> SE site has become less active over the last year in terms of # of new questions. Is this true?

An active user posted ~400 questions in 2021, and stopped posting questions in 2022-03. That alone accounts for almost half of the 2021->2022 drop in number of questions. And of course, fewer questions results in fewer answers. No idea about the other half.

Comment: perhaps it was space-question-asking burn-out due to a case of Rigelian Space-Question-Asking Fever :-)